# how to programmatically create ensembles in weka?

Tags: java, machine-learning, weka

Does there already exist a class in weka that takes care of voting/averaging different models, or do I have to come up with my own scheme?

I already looked for that kind of functionality on the web, but I couldn't find any specific information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, it already exists. Please check class [Vote](http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc.dev/weka/classifiers/meta/Vote.html).

Comment: Yes, thanks. There is even a nice short explanation on youtube https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=062w-dGDRr0